# Core Data or Keychain problems

Tags: ios, core-data, app-store, keychain

I have an app that uses core data to store some information and the keychain to store passwords and other critical information.

I've recently done an update to the app that didn't had any impact on the core data or keychain features. This worked fine in my tests (using ad hoc / enterprise profiles): the app would update from the previous version and everything would work smoothly. After submitting (and being approved) and updating the old version through the appstore, I'm having one of two problems: either the database was corrupted (or isn't accessible) or the keychain isn't accessible.

Does any one have similar cases? Something (core data or keychain) working fine in tests (including testing updates) but it suddenly stops working after submitting to the appstore?

I'm also suspecting this can be related to iOS6 / 6.0.1.

Comment: Are you saying that users with the app already installed are getting both of these errors after they update the app?

Comment: Well... core data can have issues if your model changed (you need to perform a migration). The keychain is also tricky since it is persistant storage and you may or may not remember in your testing you may have incrementally hid a problem that was originally there. Start with installing the previous version as is (after removing the app from your device). Then see if you can replicate the error after installing your update. If CoreData doesn't bum out there, I'd assume it is a keychain issue.